# Weird sticky liquid on old tripod (+10 years)

Tags: tripod, accessories, old-cameras

I found my Dad's old tripod in the garage. It is more than 10 years old and it's still in perfect condition. The problem is that there is a weird sticky liquid all over the top of the tripod near the rotationary part.

Is it the internal part that made the tripod move smootly that blew up over time? The tripod still moves smootly tough. I would like to wash the liquid, but I don't know what it is.

Model: Veldbon D-400

The liquid is very sticky almost like glue. It's around the base.

[Here's a foto](https://www.dropbox.com/s/48aekia9fd43cxn/2014-12-21%2010.54.09.jpg?dl=0)

Comment: "Weird sticky liquid" is a big vague. Does it have a color? A smell? Information on the tripod model or a photo of it may help as well.

Comment: @MitchGoshorn I've added details

Comment: I would assume it's probably silicone grease that simply seeped out of the pan-tilt mechanism over time.

Comment: Take a photo of it?

Comment: @jdlugosz I've added a photo

Comment: Velbon is still in business, so why don't you ask them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Velbon D-400 has a so-called "fluid head",
where fluid damps movements to smooth video pans.
That damping fluid probably leaked.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment on the post, it looks like some grease or lubricant. It has probably come out due to temperature variations over time if it's been in the garage. It's safe to clean it off, but I probably wouldn't use water unless you have to (part of the reason for it being inside the mechanism is to help repel water from the working parts. A slightly damp cloth should do it. If it doesn't come off straight away with that, one thing you could try is to leave the damp cloth in contact with the grease for a few minutes to help soften it so it can be cleaned off easier